# Why is this MySQL query giving me an error 1064?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This query is giving me an error 1064:

```
UPDATE `the_table_name` SET `build` = '7' WHERE `ID` = '820000',
UPDATE `the_table_name` SET `build` = '7' WHERE `ID` = '820400';
```

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `the_table_name` (
`ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`destroyedID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`flags` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`build` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77000301 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**MySQL Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax**

The first `UPDATE` line ends with a comma. Changing it to a semi-colon should fix the error.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can do this in one statement.

```
UPDATE `the_table_name` SET `build`= '7' WHERE `ID` IN(820000, 820400)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with

```
UPDATE `the_table_name` SET `build` = '7' WHERE `ID` = '820000';
UPDATE `the_table_name` SET `build` = '7' WHERE `ID` = '820400';
```